# Spring boot (2.2.4.RELEASE) on docker hangs on boot unless network_mode: host

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a dockerized springboot application, if I run the image on my machine (ubuntu) all works fine with docker network mode default, as soon I run the image on an enterprise server (VPS) with the default, it hangs on startup and stays there forever.

```
2020-03-24 08:26:47.590   INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
2020-03-24 08:26:47.821   INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-24 08:26:48.015   INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-24 08:26:48.125   INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-24 08:26:48.151   INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

or in debug

```
2020-03-24 08:19:43.856  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 43,520
2020-03-24 08:19:43.935  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7b248da4
2020-03-24 08:19:43.935  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://157.46.186.128:62013/db
2020-03-24 08:19:43.935  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         : PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.9
2020-03-24 08:19:43.935  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         :   setDefaultFetchSize = 0
2020-03-24 08:19:43.935  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         :   setPrepareThreshold = 5
2020-03-24 08:19:43.935  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to 160.46.186.128:62013
2020-03-24 08:19:43.936  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 186,240
2020-03-24 08:19:43.937  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 43,520
2020-03-24 08:19:44.007  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@205272d5
2020-03-24 08:19:44.008  DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - After adding stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
2020-03-24 08:20:10.592  DEBUG 1 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
2020-03-24 08:20:39.272  DEBUG 1 --- [alina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1585038039271 sessioncount 0
2020-03-24 08:20:39.272  DEBUG 1 --- [alina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 1 expired sessions: 0
2020-03-24 08:20:40.592  DEBUG 1 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
2020-03-24 08:21:10.593  DEBUG 1 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
2020-03-24 08:21:39.274  DEBUG 1 --- [alina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1585038099274 sessioncount 0
2020-03-24 08:21:39.274  DEBUG 1 --- [alina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
2020-03-24 08:21:40.593  DEBUG 1 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
2020-03-24 08:22:10.594  DEBUG 1 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
2020-03-24 08:22:39.277  DEBUG 1 --- [alina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1585038159277 sessioncount 0
2020-03-24 08:22:39.277  DEBUG 1 --- [alina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
2020-03-24 08:22:40.594  DEBUG 1 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
2020-03-24 08:23:10.595  DEBUG 1 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
```

I have tried to configure my custom network on docker level, use ip, hostnames and no luck.
has anyone experienced same behavior?

Spring Config:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://157.46.186.128:62013/db
    user:  user
    password: xxxxx
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    schemas: db1

datasource:
  db:
    jdbcUrl: "jdbc:postgresql://157.46.186.128:62013/db"
    username: "user"
    password: "xxxxx"
    driver-class-name: "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"
  ci:
    jdbcUrl: "jdbc:postgresql://157.46.186.128:62013/db"
    username: "user"
    password: "xxxxx"
    driver-class-name: "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"
    schema: ci
```

docker network settings:

with host mode

```
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "49fa5d5e812c816a84efe92156e825151b2dc75a36bb68c399b943e06c26a6f7",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "d6ecd673f06e15560a16dc5bb38ea4be99e751bfb729d819ab76c50320836443",
                    "EndpointID": "087b1a6fed2cd5b4de46c6700a9ef7e79de6fc3e58a0ecfdd74a8a851429eaa6",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

and without

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "cf8d68a1b1c61d454ed45eb48f4007591d07414f2147410c1381d60e12b93445",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "7979/tcp": null,
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/cf8d68a1b1c6",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "49993412f56f7bd29edd55091bd77bba66a40ae566daf8111f891be9aa21d4ce",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "bf5b2dfe32339838a40b351409fb7750f632a3810cb8774db195f49eed8a3ed5",
                    "EndpointID": "49993412f56f7bd29edd55091bd77bba66a40ae566daf8111f891be9aa21d4ce",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are these real IP addresses? Looks very odd how they're assigned. How does your config look like?

Comment: @daniel.eichten they are not real, i changed them just for example purposes. I have added the config

Comment: Ok, was puzzled by the two different IP addresses in the debug log. So I assume you have a docker container with the Postgres and another one for Spring application? So then I assume your overlay network hast the 160 network?

Comment: How do you create the network? And how do you declare the network to be used by the containers?

Comment: PostgreSQL runs on a different server, 157.46.186.128 as example, i did not create a network manually, i just performed the docker run command and without the flag --network="host" it hangs forever. But on my local machine no issues

Comment: I changed the title to better reflect the problem as I believe that pg connects but something is happening after

Comment: Well `network_mode: host` usually speaks for a twist in IP addresses. So just to be clear: as I see private 172 networks in docker networking. The 157 is the IP of the host machine and did you expose Postgres with `-p` on `docker run`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set docker daemon MTU to be the same as the network card.

**ip link show**

```
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> **mtu 1450** qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc
```

edited  **/etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
  "mtu": 1450
}
```

Problem solved. Tricky one, when I did remote debugging I notice that it was blocking on socket read, from there google was my friend.

https://mlohr.com/docker-mtu/